# Counting times that a number repeats without array(c++)

Tags: c++

I need a program to get 100 numbers between 0-20 and count the repition of the most repeated number.
Here is what I got for less amount for input (10 instead of 100) but ofc it's wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num, x,c;

    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        cin >> num;
        if(num==x)
            c++;
        else
            x=num;
    }

    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you test whether `num == x` for the first time, `x` is uninitialized and its value is indeterminate, The same applies to `c++`, where you just increment an indeterminate "garbage" value.

Comment: As for your algorithm, you need a means to store the current stretch of repetitions and the longest repetitin so far. You'll also have to reset the counter of repetitions when the number changes.

Comment: If your compiler isn't warning you about things like this, tune the options till it does (`-Wall -Wextra` is good for gcc and clang).

Comment: You should also test your input operation to make sure it succeeds before trying to use the variable read (`if (!(std::cin >> num)) { /* Handle error */ }`)

Comment: *without array* -- So how are you going to keep track if the data is `1 2 3 2 3 2 3 1 1 1`?  The `1` is repeated 4 times, but that is not known until the last element is read.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The question only makes sense if the task is to find the longest sequence of repeated numbers. I think that is the case.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie after giving exactly 100 numbers

Comment: @Shawn why should i ger error?
as i siad the code is obviously wrong
i just need ideas to help it work 
like an algorithm of checking numbers or these stuff

Comment: If you get input that can't be interpreted as a number. What if the user gives you "cat" instead?

Comment: @Shawn the user is my teacher so ofc she'll handle it when she says use only loops and conditionals   :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the longest continuous sequence, here's one way you can do it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int max_val = 0, max_len = 0;  // Overall longest
  int cur_val = 0, cur_len = 0;  // Current

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    int val;
    std::cin >> val;     // read 1 number
    if (val == cur_val)  // if still counting the same, increment the length
      ++cur_len;
    else {  // else, set the max and reset current
      if (cur_len > max_len) {
        max_len = cur_len;
        max_val = cur_val;
      }
      cur_len = 1;
      cur_val = val;
    }
  }

  // consider the very last sequence
  if (cur_len > max_len) {
    max_len = cur_len;
    max_val = cur_val;
  }

  // Result
  std::cout << "Longest seq: " << max_val << ", length: " << max_len << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help 
but i can only use basic command like loops and conditionals.

Comment: @athena you can replace `max = std::max(max, cur, sequence_len_less)` with a simple conditional assignment. The rest has nothing fancy I guess.

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)